# Javafx problem setting ImageView inside my BorderPane

Tags: java, javafx

What I have:

I have a BorderPane, my BorderPane consists of 2 parts, top and center. Inside top part I have ImageView which i want to set and inside center part I have a pane in which I have a button and this button should change the image inside ImageView. The BorderPane as a whole is one FXML file controlled with BorderPaneController but the center part (pane) is another FXML file controlled wtih CenterPaneController.

What I want to do:
The imageview show my new image after i click the button

What is my problem:

When I click the button the image path is successfuly transfered from CenterPaneController to BorderPaneController and also the ImageView is successfuly set, because it contains the image path but the Image View is still empty

this is the FXML file of the center part (pane) of the BorderPane where I have the button:

```
<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ProfilPouzivatelaController">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="434.0" layoutY="227.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#insertImagePath" onMouseClicked="#vlozFotku" text="Zmeniť profilovú fotku" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

this is the FXML file of the BorderPane where I have my ImageView in the top part:

```
<BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1400.0" stylesheets="hlavnePouzivatelskeRozhranie.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="PouzivatelskeRozhranieController">
   <top>
      <HBox fx:id="topHBox" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="800.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>            
            <HBox fx:id="innerHbox" alignment="CENTER_LEFT" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="54.0" prefWidth="148.0">
               <children>
                  <ImageView fx:id="image" fitHeight="50.0" fitWidth="60.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />                                       
               </children>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </top>
```

code of my BorderPaneController:

```
public class BorderPaneController  {
    @FXML
    private ImageView image;

    public void setImage(String imagePath) {
        this.image.setImage(new Image(imagePath));
     
    }    

}
```

This is the code of my CenterPaneController:

```
public class CenterPaneController {
    private BorderPaneController borderPane; 
    
    @FXML
    public void insertImagePath(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {

        FXMLLoader loader = new   FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("borderPane.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        borderPane = loader.getController();
        borderPane.setImage("Obrazky//default.png");
}
```

Comment: This path is wrong -> `"Obrazky//default.png"` -> it has two slashes.  Here is a space cat image [https://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/lovely_space_kitten-t2.jpg](https://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/lovely_space_kitten-t2.jpg).  Try setting the image to that exact URL.  If it works, the problem is with where you are placing your local image, or with the path you are using to find it; in which case, see [how to find resources for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other).

Comment: I tried but the issue has to do something that I am creating new instance of the BorderPane so instead I am changing imageview of the "other" BorderPane which is not shown.

Comment: Create and post a [mre].

Comment: If your `insertImagePath()` method is complete, then of course nothing will happen: you are loading the FXML but not displaying its content anywhere, so you will not see the image.

Comment: Probably the best approach to this is to use a [MVC approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx)  where your model class has an observable `Property<Image>` which is observed by one controller and modified by the other.